# AWS Webapp tutorial: how to choose source in database security group?

Tags: amazon-web-services, web-applications, amazon-ec2

I am following the AWS tutorial to create a Webapp here: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/gettingstarted/latest/wah-linux/getting-started-create-rds.html

I am stuck at the part 'Create a Security Group for Your DB Instance'.

The tutorial instructs you to start writing 'WebserverSG' into the IP source, and to select an option. However, even after completely typing 'WebserverSG', no such option is presented and I am unable to create the security group.

Is there a way to know the source without selecting it from the options? Alternatively, have I done something wrong for the option to not be presented?

This is my first time dealing with AWS; I don't have a *concrete* understanding of the purpose of security groups - so please bear this in mind!

Thanks in advance for any answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was fixed by: remaking the web server security group with the exact name WebServerSG, then making the database security group by starting typing the inbound IP with 'sg-...' instead of 'WebSe...'. Assigning the new security group to a similar instance has everything working.

Answer (score 0):

Are you going through the VPC area of the console or trying to edit it from within RDS? If I remember correctly you can only enter another Security Group as a source from within the VPC area.